# juju redundancy

Tags: juju

I use juju to deploy OpenStack (using MAAS as the provider). In my current setup, the juju 'master' is deployed to my machine 0. If that machine goes offline I lose the ability to modify the juju environment or even to 'juju ssh' to individual containers (since machine 0 is used as a jump-host).  That's not ideal.

How can I make juju deployment more robust, so it can survive a crash of a single machine?

Answer (score 2):

The juju documentation has a section about High Availability:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/controllers-ha

Comment: Thx, somehow I've completely missed that section